# ¿como minimizar y maximizar?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Que tal que evento necesito para poder minimizar y maximizar, pero dando click
en el icono de mi aplicación desde la barra de tareas?

lo único que tengo es el siguiente código:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Este evento no existe en Windows Forms, pero puedes detectar un cambio en el tamaño de la forma con el evento `SizeChanged` y comprarndo los `WindowState`s de la forma.